# PHP Recursively print each part of URL

Tags: php, function, url, recursion, explode

I have a question about making a recursive function in PHP. What better way to print all the states of a URL after dividing it by '/'?

PS: The base case would be based of the URL
e.g http://www.domain.com

What I need is:

example:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/1/2/3/4';

function strip_states($url){
  ?????
}

strip_states();

// Result
// print -> http://www.site.com.br/1/2/3
// print -> http://www.site.com.br/1/2
// print -> http://www.site.com.br/1
// print -> http://www.site.com.br
```

I'm totally lost.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “state”, and what practical use the above case would actually have?

Comment: i'll search for each "state" of URL in database for matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.domain.com/1/2/3/4';

$parts = explode('/', $url);

for ($i=count($parts); $i>=3; $i--) {
    echo implode('/', $parts) . PHP_EOL;
    array_pop($parts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.domain.com/1/2/3/4';

function strip_states($url)
{
    $url_parts = parse_url($url);
    $host = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'];

    if(false === isset($url_parts['path'])) {
        echo $host;
        return;
    }

    foreach(explode('/', $url_parts['path']) as $key => $part) 
    {
        if($key)
        {
             echo $host .= '/' . $part;
         echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}

strip_states($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not recursive, but i hope it helps you in some way:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/1/2/3/4';
strip_url($url);


function strip_url($url)
{
$largo = strlen($url);
$aux = ""; $cont = 0;
echo $url." len $largo"."</br>";

for ($i=0; $i<$largo; $i++)
{   
    if($url[$i]=="/"){$cont++;}  
    $aux = $aux.$url[$i];

    if($cont > 2 && $url[$i]=="/")
    echo $aux."</br>";    
}
echo $aux."</br>"; 


}
```

Saludos from Chile ;)